# Sigma algebra generated of two partitions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $(A_1, ..., A_m)$ and $(B_1, ... B_n)$ are two partitions of $\Omega$, show that:

(a) $(Ai\cap Bj)$ is a partition of $\Omega$.

(b) $\sigma \{ \sigma\{A_i\} \cup \sigma\{B_j\} \} = \sigma \{ A_i \cap B_j \} = \sigma(\{ A_i\} \cup \{B_j \})$

I´ve already proof (a) but I´m having trouble understanding the meaning of the Sigma algebra generated and I don´t know how to get the Sigma algebra generated of an union or intersection. I don´t see any properties for that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of understanding the definitions, $\sigma\{\cdots\}$ means "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains the sets listed in the braces."

So $\sigma\{\{A_i \cap B_j\}\}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all sets of the form $A_i \cap B_j$, for all $i$ and $j$.

Similarly $\sigma\{\sigma\{A_i\} \cup \sigma\{B_j\}\}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the sets in the smaller $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma\{A_i\}$ and $\sigma\{B_j\}$.

---

Typically, a strategy to prove $\sigma\{\mathcal{A}\} = \sigma\{\mathcal{B}\}$ (for some collections of sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$) is to prove $\sigma\{\mathcal{A}\} \subseteq \sigma\{\mathcal{B}\}$ and $\sigma\{\mathcal{A}\} \supseteq \sigma\{\mathcal{B}\}$.

To prove $\sigma\{\mathcal{A}\} \subseteq \sigma\{\mathcal{B}\}$, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \sigma\{\mathcal{B}\}$. Then, $\sigma\{\mathcal{B}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$, and thus must contain $\sigma\{\mathcal{A}\}$ since this is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$.